# why am i getting error of AttributeError at /admin/main/consultation/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lastname'

Tags: python, django, django-models

in my admin page when i click on consultation i am getting this error

#model.py

```
class doctor(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    
    is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default='')
    dob = models.DateField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    countrycode=models.CharField(max_length=5)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    registration_no = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    year_of_registration = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    medical_experience = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    medical_council=models.CharField(max_length=80,default='')
    charges = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profilephoto = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to="dprofile/")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Dr. " + self.firstname +" "+ self.lastname

class consultation(models.Model):

    patient = models.ForeignKey(patient ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(doctor ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    diseaseinfo = models.OneToOneField(diseaseinfo, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    consultation_date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.firstname + " "+self.doctor.lastname + '- Dr.' +self.doctor.firstname + ' ' +self.doctor.lastname
```

Comment: The `__str__` method of `consultation` uses `self.doctor.lastname`, while the field `doctor` has `null=True` meaning there can be instances which don't have an entry for doctor, which in fact is what has happened...

Comment: so how can i fix  this ?????

Comment: That is upto you how you want the string representation to be if there is no related doctor. A bunch of if-else conditions to return the correct representation? Or if there absolutely should be a related doctor then your model schema is incorrect. You would need to fill the missing values and remove that `null=True`.

Comment: but the doctor model has value of  lastname name and firstname present in database still its not showing and can you edit my code or share any docs related to this as i am pretty much new to django

Comment: Write `python manage.py shell` in your terminal / cmd to open up a python shell with Django configured. Now in this shell import the models and write `consultation.objects.filter(doctor=None)`. You will see that you have instances which have no related doctor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `consultation` has two *nullable* fields `patient` and `doctor`. This means that `self.patikent` and `self.doctor` are not per se a `patient` and `doctor` object, but can be `None` as well.

You thus should cover the case where you these fields are `None`:

```
class consultation(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(patient ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(doctor ,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    diseaseinfo = models.OneToOneField(diseaseinfo, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    consultation_date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        names = []
        if self.patient is not None:
            names.append(f'{self.patient.firstname} {self.patient.lastname}')
        if self.doctor is not None:
            names.append(f'Dr. {self.doctor.firstname} {self.doctor.lastname}')
        return ' - '.join(names)
```

It however looks odd that `patient` and `doctor` can be `NULL` in the first place. It means a consultation can have no patient and/or doctor?

Comment: Has Fixed that model relationship mess, that thanks for reminding ...